# Android Studio The following classes could not be instantiated android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

Tags: android-studio, gui

Как это убрать? `The following classes could not be instantiated android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  
Exception Details java.lang.NullPointerException   
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:747)
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)
at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:212)   
at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:206)   
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)   
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)   
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)   
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)   
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)   
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)   
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:221)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:143) Copy stack to clipboard
```

Перепробовал, наверное, все способы, которые нашел в интернете, ничего не помогло. Ни в одном из активити не использую `AppCompatTextView`. Все подключаемые библиотеки:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'

compile 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
```

Может есть способ скрыть это объявление в настройках? Или возможность объяснить `Android Studio`, что все подключено?

Тема стоит `parent='Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'`

**П.с.** Оно мешается и не дает делать дизайн, вылезает после любой правки в `xml` коде, через неделю работы уже задолбался закрывать крестиком.

[image: Мешается!]

Answer (score 5):

В конце концов разобрался. Видел в интернете ответ 'Добавить в `parent` Base. в начале', но выдавало ошибку, т.к. `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` не существует.

**Как убрать это объявление, если у вас NoActionBar**

`style.xml` Добавить эти строчки в `<resources>`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

`style.xml` Заменить parent в AppTheme на это

```
parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

В `ThemeEditor` выбрать `AppTheme.NoActionBar`

Как итог: объявление исчезло!) Может кому-нибудь поможет

Answer (score 3):

Ну если уж просто взять и спрятать, как Вы и пытались сделать, то заверните в трай-кетч проблемный кусок кода.  Или понажимайте на варианты которые Вам предлагают:

```
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.
```

Comment: try catch не получится, эта ошибка вылезает не из моих файлов, `rebuild + refresh` пробовал, ничего не дало. Про `isInEditMode()` почти ничего не понял, понял только, что его нужно писать в свои файлы, а как я уже сказал, ошибка лезет не из моих файлов